Polynomial time approximation on a similar problem to Densest-k-Subgraph
Given a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices. Each vertex has a weight $w_i$. For any subgraph $H$, define a function for each vertex of $H$, $f(v_i)$, to be the average of the weight of $v_i$ and all weights of vertices adjacent to $v_i$. That is, $f(v_i)=(w_i+\sum_{(v_i,v_j)\in E(H)}w_j)/(d_H(v_i)+1)$. I want to find a subgraph $H$ with $m$ vertices such that $\sum_{v_i\in V(H)}f(v_i)$ is maximized.
I would like an approximation algorithm in polynomial time. Note that this is similar to Densest-k-Subgraph, but not exactly since each vertex's contribution is calculated separately. Also, $G$ is given and can be preprocessed: the vertex weights are the only problem parameters. Any ideas are appreciated.

With $m$ vertices or with at most $m$ vertices?  I believe that can be a crucial difference, since there is no approximation algorithm for Densest $\leq k$-Subgraph.

@JohnKemeny Exactly $m$ vertices - thanks for pointing out. The difference between this problem and Densest $k$-Subgraph is that the graph $G$ is given in advance and can be arbitrarily preprocessed, only the vertex weights are unknown. In the classic Densest $k$-Subgraph you can just examine all subgraphs if there is no vertex weight.
